# The Error message ""index" argument is expected to be a number, but it was number" is unclear

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

While writing automated test for a website I got the following very odd error in here are the relovent lines of code:

```
  68    let selected
  69    if( params.includes('-RB') ){
  70         let books = Selector('.actions > .link-learn > div').withText('VIEW PRODUCT')
  71         const index = books.count
  72         selected = books.nth( Math.floor(Math.random() * index) );
  73     }
```

and testcafe is making the following complaint at line 72.

```
 "index" argument is expected to be a number, but it was number.
```

And there are no strings, variables, etc. named with name number in my program.  So what does this error mean and maybe this error should throw a different message that is slightly more clear.

thanks

Comment: why the down vote, I feel like this is a legitimate question?

Comment: Because it was severely edited to provide appropriate information after the vote was cast..

Comment: the only thing I added what line 68 since it dealt with a variable in the function?  Though I accidentally posted it before ctr-K?  but is no big deal I just wanted to know if I was asking a dumb question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have missed `await` on the line 71. It must be

```
const index = await books.count
```

Without `await`, you get a Promise wrapper instead of the actual [count](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/selector/count.html) property. On the next line, the Promise turns into `NaN` (not a number) in the `Math.random() * index` expression. Type validation fails because `NaN` is not a valid number, but in JavaScript `NaN` belongs to the `number` type, which is reported in error message. That's why error report has the silly `expected to be a number, but it was number` message.

Thank your for the feedback and helping me to capture a bug, I've created an issue about it: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2470. I think we will fix it in the next release.

Comment: Thanks so much that makes since I didn't even think about needing to await the count :)